# how can i make this section using grid system?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-grid

[The SIte i am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzA3R.png)

how can i structure this section using Bootstrap4 Grid System ?

Note : without this sticy navbar

hope you guys help me :)

Comment: Give a description of your image and explain your question in a detailed manner. Else you may get fewer views and more downvotes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to understand the grid system in bootstrap well, you should know that each row contains 12 columns and organizing them is really easy.please visit :https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp . 
but your answer is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" style="background-color:green;">main</div>
  <div class="col" style="background-color:orange;">
<div class="col" style="background-color:orange;border: 1px solid black">
  1
</div>
<div class="col" style="background-color:orange;border: 1px solid black">
  2
</div>
</div>
 <div class="col" style="background-color:lavender">
 <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid black">
  1
 </div>
 <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid black">
  2
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```